# Torrent: Webseed or seeding client on server?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, rtorrent

I want to share a file using bittorent which I also offer over http.
The torrent should be seeded by a dedicated and a virtual server and by people who are downloading it to lower bandwidth costs.

My question: Should I set up a bittorrent client (rtorrent) on the servers and let them seed the file or should I use webseeds? I also want to limit the bandwidth the server uses to seed which is possible using rTorrent.

How many bittorrent clients support webseeds? I found it in µTorrent and never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients that support Web Seeding

BitTornado v5.0 or higher

Mainline

Utorrent v1.7 or higher

BitComet v1.14 or higher

There may be more

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)#Web_seeding